# Is it possible to implement a custom MATLAB-like array/matrix type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, operator-overloading, tostring

For instance, imagine I'd like to create a Matlab-like matrix type, which can be accessed by index using square braces and which has a custom toString() method (so a matrix A, indexed like A[i][j], which supports print(A) and possibly other custom methods like appending or deleting). In C++, I could just create a class initialized with an array or vector parameter and overload the << and [] operators to simulate such an object. But without operator overloading, I'm left to do something like this (apologies for the bad practices, I've been learning Java for about four hours).

```
class PrintList {

    private int[][] arr;

    public PrintList(int[][] a) {
        this.arr = a;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i != arr.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j != arr[0].length; ++j) {
                str += String.format("%5d", arr[i][j]);
            }
            str += '\n';
        }
        return str;
    }

    public int[][] getArr() { return this.arr; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}};
        PrintList arr = new PrintList(a);
        System.out.println(arr.getArr()[0][2]); // I have to access the array indices by first accessing the array, preventing me from customizing its behavior.
        System.out.println(arr); // this works
    }
}
```

This supports sout.print(), but accessing the data requires me to access the internal array structure which I'd ideally like to hide inside my "matrix wrapper". Is the "Java-esque" solution to use an object like this based on simple arrays (or maybe ArrayLists), and to customize behavior within custom getter and setter methods, or is there some other more elegant way to create a custom data structure like this? Could I instead inherit from ArrayList and implement custom behavior in the child class?

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is not possible in Java.

Arrays, and only arrays, can be accessed by `[]`. You can't overload it.

I think the best thing to do here is to create a utility method like this:

```
public class MatrixHelper {
    public static String toString(int[][] matrix) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you look closely in the JDK, `Arrays` is such a class, providing various helper methods for 1D arrays, including `toString`. In `Arrays`, `toString` is available for all primitive types and there is also a generic version of it to support reference types. You can also make your `MatrixHelper` this way if that is needed.